# Why is truffle returning <indexed> instead of the actual value of the event?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have indexed some values on my events. When I run tests, why don't they show up ?

Example :

```
Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

Upgrade(_tokenId: <indexed>, _upgradeType: 1)

---------------------------
```

Why isn't it showing the token id?

Answer (score 0):

The callback return object is different depending on if you create a [global filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) or a [contract filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events). You'd need to add your client code to give a better answer, but this looks like a global filter whose response separates out the event data (non-indexed fields) from the topics (the indexed fields). From the documentation:

> - data: String - contains one or more 32 Bytes non-indexed arguments of the log.
> - topics: Array of Strings - Array of 0 to 4 32 Bytes DATA of indexed log arguments. (In solidity: The first topic is the hash of the signature of the event (e.g. Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)), except if you declared the event with the anonymous specifier.)

With a contract filter, you can get to each argument using `args` regardless if it's indexed or not.

Example:

```
var contractFilter = contractInstance.Upgrade({}, (e, r) => {
  console.log(r.args._tokenId);
});
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your response! Unforunately I don't understand, is there a link that further explains this ?

Comment: Did you click the links in my post?

Answer (score 0):

My `truffle-assertions` library can log all emitted events inside a transaction in the same way as truffle normally outputs them on error, except that it also displays indexed arguments' values correctly.

The library can be installed through npm

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

Then, it can be imported at the top of your test file

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
```

And finally it can be used to output all emitted events inside a transaction.

```
let result = contractInstance.function({from: account[0]});
truffleAssert.prettyPrintEmittedEvents(result);
```

Comment: how do you make it work particular to this library, if the solidity function is a get function with a return value+ a event emit. The first param in ```truffleAssert.eventEmitted``` wants a tx receipt , but You would get a result value....

Comment: You can't meaningfully emit events in a view function. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46198/emit-event-in-view-function-or